# Change the colour of Mediaelements.js player

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, mediaelement.js

How do I change the colour of the mediaelements.js player?
It's black but I need to change it to blue...

Ideally I'd like the black background to be transparent and just show the progress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to change a few lines in the css file named `mediaelementplayer.css` located in `src/css`:

First find the line `.mejs-container {` and comment out the `background-color` property like so:

```
/*background: #000;*/
```

Next, find the line `.mejs-container .mejs-controls {`, should be at 150.
Then remove all of the background properties, these ones:

```
background: url(background.png);
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(50,50,50,0.7)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0.7)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(50,50,50,0.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.7));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(50,50,50,0.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.7));
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(50,50,50,0.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.7));
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(50,50,50,0.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.7));
background: linear-gradient(rgba(50,50,50,0.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.7));
```

Replace them by the following line:

```
background: transparent;
```

Make your you use the right css file where the attributes have been changed.

Comment: that allows you to change the colour but setting background: transparent; makes the entire player invisible!

Comment: It should not, did you make sure you changed the right lines?

Comment: Okay, I uploaded the demo with the changed lines [here](http://mediaplayer.theonlyerror.nl/johndyer-mediaelement-64dcb19/demo/mediaelementplayer.html). As you can see the background is transparent. Or isn't that what you ment?

Comment: the player background is black when it's set to transparent, you'll see if you use an audio file rather than a video file.

Comment: Check my edited answer, that should solve your problem. Demo can be found [here](http://mediaplayer.theonlyerror.nl/johndyer-mediaelement-64dcb19/demo/mediaelementplayer-audio.html).

Answer (score 0):

My solution -- make sure to insert this style AFTER the media element's default style. It will overwrite the background image that was previously set, with a color for the control bar background:

```
    .mejs-container .mejs-controls {
        background: red;
    }
```